# Accessing function of class A from RESTful API that runs in class B

Tags: python, rest

I have the following code

```
import time
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
import threading

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)


class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 5

    def increment_x(self):
        self.x += 1

    def get_x(self):
        return self.x


def a_runner(b):
    while True:
        b.increment_x()
        print(b.get_x())
        time.sleep(5)


class B:
    def __init__(self, ref: A):
        class GetAssetPairs(Resource):
            def __init__(self, int_ref: A):
                self.inst_of_A = int_ref

            def get(self):
                return {'test': self.inst_of_A.get_x()}

        api.add_resource(GetAssetPairs, '/test', resource_class_kwargs={'int_ref': ref})
        app.run(port='5003', debug=False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    b = A()
    bot_th = threading.Thread(target=a_runner, args=(b,), daemon=True)
    bot_th.start()
    c = B(b)
```

Is there a more proper way to have access to functions of `class A` through the REST Api instead of passing it to the `Resource` class using the `resource_class_kwargs`? This implementation works but feels like it's a hack and not very scalable if the API grows.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Is this code from a real project? If not, your question is _off-topic_. You may want to attend the [help] to inform yourself what questions can be asked here.

Comment: This code smells hypothetical, hence the downvotes and requests for closing the question. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic] to see what is and isn't an acceptable question here. Thank you.

Comment: I'll do, sorry for that. It's not hypothetical as such, the project is just growing and I used this as a system design verification.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with that. Does this mean the current code is a mock-up, a proof-of-concept?

Comment: It isn't doing anything useful yet, is it?

Comment: What is your goal with this code? What made you write it? What problem does it solve? Context is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial approach is over-complicated and has issues in design, namings and relations.

*Class **`A`***

The **`get_x`** method makes no sense for returning *public* attribute `self.x` value - that `x` attribute is accessible directly. Instead, it's better to apply [`@property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) decorator (provides a "getter" for a read-only attribute with the same name) to "protected" `self._x` attribute/field.

The **`a_runner`** function is coupled/dependent on specific behavior (`increment_x`, `get_x`) inherent to class `A` instance. Thus, it's better and reasonably moved to be  a part of class **`A`** scope. Time delay can be flexibly used/adjusted via additional keyword argument with default value **`delay=5`**

The optimized class `A` definition:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, init_value=5):
        self._x = init_value

    def increment_x(self):
        self._x += 1

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    def run(self, delay=5):
        while True:
            self.increment_x()
            print(self.x)
            time.sleep(delay)
```

---

*Class **`B`***

Flask API is usually declared at top level as `api = Api(app)` and it's absolutely normal to add/register resources `api.add_resource` at the same level.
Class `B` is redundant as itself. 
Class `GetAssetPairs` is defined as top-level class for custom resource. Using `resource_class_kwargs` feature is normal and designed for that cases.

The rest part, optimized:

```
class GetAssetPairs(Resource):
    def __init__(self, a_instance: A):
        self.a_instance = a_instance

    def get(self):
        return {'test': self.a_instance.x}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = A()
    bot_th = threading.Thread(target=a.run, daemon=True)
    bot_th.start()

    api.add_resource(GetAssetPairs, '/test', resource_class_kwargs={'a_instance': a})
    app.run(port='5003', debug=False)
```

Comment: In the future, please refrain from answering off-topic questions. There are plenty of questions within the current site-scope that could use an answer instead. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].